# Tricky delete. How do i?

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I got a table with 2 columns (both INT), and there are 400 000  records (a lot).
The first column is random numbers ordered ASC. The second column has a rule on it (which is not important right now)
In the table there are 1000 records, that are exceptions. So, instead of the "rule", there is only "-1" - valued cells.

How can I delete ~399 000 records, so i want to have in my table left only the ones with -1 and their "neighbors" (the records before and after the ones with -1)

UPDATE
sql server 2k5
first column values - yes unique, but not ID-s (it's not ++ :D)

example:

before:

```
 20022518   13
 20022882   364
 20022885   -1
 20022887   5
 20022905   18
 20023200   295
 20023412   212
 20023696   284
 20024112   416
 20025015   903
 20025400   385
 20025401   -1
 20025683   283
 20025981   298
 20025989   8
 20026752   763
 20027779   1027
 20028344   565
 20028350   6
 20028896   546
 20028921   25
 20028924   -1
 20028998   77
 20029031   33
 20029051   20
 20029492   441
 20029530   38
 20029890   360
```

after:

```
 20022882   364
 20022885   -1
 20022887   5
 20025400   385
 20025401   -1
 20025683   283
 20028921   25
 20028924   -1
 20028998   77
```

Comment: What database are you using (Oracle, Sql-Server, MySQL, ...)? Are the values of your first column unique?

Comment: is before/after defined by consecutive id's or some other field?  or just by the position or order-of-insert into the table?

Comment: Yikes, that's a nasty problem you've got there.  I think Peter Lang makes a good point.  If values in the first column aren't unique, you can't guarantee which of the two will be deleted even if there is a solution to this problem (at least not without more criteria).

Comment: which database? for previous and next there are differences...

Comment: There is no order in a table (in a set). What if I gave you a bag of balls and asked you to give me the 3rd and 8th ball? Your RDBMS work the same way, if you don't tell him exactly what to do, he'll either screw up everything or do nothing. Anyway, you'll most likely have to use a temporary table, I'll try to come up with something (but it would be easier if you gave us the structure of your table).

Comment: @Vincent, if you gave me a bag of balls and tell me to give you 3rd and 8th ball looking at the first field written on each ball, I would be perfectly capable of giving you such a subset. Similarly, if you read the question carefully you will see that OP is mentioning ascending order by first column and I would say that it would be safe to assume that in this sense the "neighbours" are defined.

Comment: @Swoosh, can you explain exactly why would you need the "neighbours"?

Comment: @Unreason: You can't say a column is ordered. That is the problem. There is no order in a table, period. You can't assume data are already ordered. Which is why I told him he'll most likely have to use a temporary table, because you can't `UPDATE ... ORDER BY`. If I asked you to remove every red balls from the bag, and keep the first 5 green balls next to them based on the date I added them (let's assume I wrote the date on the balls!) you'd first have to sort all the balls, remove the unwanted one and keep the one based on the previous sort.

Comment: @JNK, Vincent - ok, as the faq says this is not a forum :) My point is that the question is well defined in terms of relational algebra.

Comment: i added more details an example

Comment: and YES the data was imported already ordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to keep all records with col2 = -1 and the records with the closest col1 to the records with -1. Assuming no duplicates in col1 I would do something like this

```
delete from table where not col1 in 
(
    (select col1 from table where col2 = -1)
union
    (select (select max(t2.col1) from table t2 where t2.col1 < t1.col1) from table t1 where t1.col2 = -1)
union
    (select (select min(t4.col1) from table t4 where t4.col1 > t3.col1) from table t3 where t3.col2 = -1)
)
```

**Edit:**
`t4.col1 < t3.col1` should be `t4.col1 > t3.col1`
I created a test-table with col1 and col2, both int, col1 is PK, but not autonumber

```
SELECT * from adjacent
```

Gives

```
col1    col2
1   5
3   4
4   2
7   -1
11  8
12  2
```

With the above subselects:

```
SELECT * from adjacent
where
col1 in 
(
    (select col1 from adjacent where col2 = -1)
union
    (select (select max(t2.col1) from adjacent t2 where t2.col1 < t1.col1) from adjacent t1 where t1.col2 = -1)
union
    (select (select min(t4.col1) from adjacent t4 where t4.col1 > t3.col1) from adjacent t3 where t3.col2 = -1)
)
```

gives

```
col1    col2
4   2
7   -1
11  8
```

With the `not` also

```
SELECT * from adjacent
where
col1 not in 
(
    (select col1 from adjacent where col2 = -1)
union
    (select (select max(t2.col1) from adjacent t2 where t2.col1 < t1.col1) from adjacent t1 where t1.col2 = -1)
union
    (select (select min(t4.col1) from adjacent t4 where t4.col1 > t3.col1) from adjacent t3 where t3.col2 = -1)
)
```

gives

```
col1    col2
1   5
3   4
12  2
```

Finally a delete and select

```
delete from adjacent
where
col1 not in 
(
    (select col1 from adjacent where col2 = -1)
union
    (select (select max(t2.col1) from adjacent t2 where t2.col1 < t1.col1) from adjacent t1 where t1.col2 = -1)
union
    (select (select min(t4.col1) from adjacent t4 where t4.col1 > t3.col1) from adjacent t3 where t3.col2 = -1)
)

select * from adjacent
```

gives

```
col1    col2
4   2
7   -1
11  8
```

Comment: your script deletes everything from my table

Comment: @Swoosh, hmm, there was a minor bug, I fixed that and added an example.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL Server here.  Your best bet, if  you are keeping a very small dataset, is to insert into a new table.  I.E.:

```
SELECT *
INTO MyTable2
FROM MyTable
WHERE ColumnB = -1

DROP TABLE MyTable

exec sp_rename MyTable2 MyTable
```

This will be a minimally logged operation and will run in a fraction of the time of a `DELETE`.

Without another key there is no way to ensure you get the "neighbors" since this is not really a valid concept in a relational DB.  If the first column is "random" you can't tell which ones are "before" and "after" a row with a -1 value.

If by "random" you mean it's like an `IDENTITY` column that increases automatically, **AND YOU HAVE NO MISSING VALUES IN THE SEQUENCE** you can do something like:

```
SELECT *
INTO MyTable2
FROM MyTable mt
WHERE ColumnB = -1
OR WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM MyTable mt2
     WHERE mt2.id = mt.id + 1
     OR mt2.id = mt.id -1)

DROP TABLE MyTable

exec sp_rename MyTable2 MyTable
```

Comment: We should emphasize that the second approach has a pretty enormous caveat, in that it requires no values to be missing from the identity sequence...

Comment: @DJacobson - I'll note that for the OP

Comment: first column is random but is ASC order, so that can be used

Comment: it's like delete all from prime numbers where the prime number is not the closest to 1000, 1500, 5000 (closest "left" and closest "right")

Comment: @Swoosh - This method won't work if your numbers aren't sequential.  I think you have a couple of options.  The **EASIEST** is just to add an `INT Identity` column to your table, and use that the my second query.  That will definitely ascend with no gaps.  You just don't copy that column to your new table, but you won't need it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to number the records first, identify those adjacent to the -1 rules and then use UNION to assemble the final result:

```
WITH Numbered(seq, id, ruleno) AS (
 SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id), id, ruleno
 FROM
  Tricky
),
Brothers(id, ruleno) AS (
 SELECT
  b.id, b.ruleno
 FROM
  Numbered a INNER JOIN Numbered b
  ON a.ruleno = -1 AND
  abs(a.seq - b.seq) = 1
),
Triplets(id, ruleno) AS (
 SELECT
  id, ruleno
 FROM
  Tricky
 WHERE
  ruleno = -1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
  id, ruleno
 FROM
  Brothers
)
-- Display results
SELECT 
 id, ruleno
FROM
 Triplets
ORDER BY
 id
```

Result:

```
id ruleno
20022882 364
20022885 -1
20022887 5
20025400 385
20025401 -1
20025683 283
20028921 25
20028924 -1
20028998 77
```

Finally:

```
DELETE FROM
  Tricky
WHERE
  id NOT IN (
    SELECT 
      id
    FROM
      triplets
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

USe this tricky query:

for this I created a table by below statement:
create table t1 (val int, val2 int)
GO

-- below is the exact stmt:

With CTE as(select val, val2, row_number() over (order by val ASC) as rnum 
from t1) 
DELETE t1
From t1 inner join cte a 
ON t1.val = a.val INNER JOIN (SELECT * fROM cte where val2 = -1) as b
on a.rnum = b.rnum
or a.rnum = b.rnum - 1
or a.rnum = b.rnum + 1

For more information baout CTE please see this post:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/08/sql-server-multiple-cte-in-one-select-statement-query/